# Do votes on answers that get deleted still count against your daily limit?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, voting-limits

I down voted on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629206/what-is-in-java-the-system-default-package).  I received the message that I only had 4 votes left for the day.   I came back because if the answer was changed I was going to remove my vote.  I found that the answer had been deleted.  However the next vote I placed gave me the message that I had 3 votes left.

I assumed that since the answer had been deleted my vote would no longer count against my daily limit.  My question is 'What should happen'?

*Disclaimer: It might actually work like I assumed and I might have not realized that I voted somewhere else in between. I am just curious how it should work.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, votes on deleted posts still count towards your limit, because the vote is still in the system. It doesn't give reputation, but it sticks around on the deleted question.

If the post were to be undeleted, the vote would still be there. If you did get votes back, then deletion and undeletion could let one vote more times per day than the daily limit.