# How is it that I have 42 votes on SO for the day?

Tags: bug, voting, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day)

Just like the question asks.. this is what I see... is this a bug in the counting? I'm certain I didn't *really* vote 42 times, I imagine the UI isn't correct in reporting.

[image]

Comment: @Lucifer - He is not saying that he was upvoted 42 times, but that he supposedly have voted 42 times on other posts, when he hasn't. I Don't  see why he deserves a *Congratulation* comment

Comment: possible duplicate: [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124172/164012)

Comment: It's also curious that you earned 605 rep this week, but only 61 this month.  Looks like the calculator is working on this being the first of the month (only one day of rep), but also a Friday (several days earlier this week).  That would make more sense if those were sliding 7-day and 30-day totals.  I mention this because it appears that you were quite active.  Did you vote at all in the last 5 days? Your vote totals don't have a similar discrepancy.

Comment: That's how I missed that, I was searching for "41 votes" and "42 votes"

Comment: @KevinVermeer I did have more rep activity this week than I did with voting, mostly edits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably voted on two posts that were deleted later on the same day. Those votes count with regard to your total no. of votes, but don't count with regard to the daily voting limit.

Comment: @CDSmith If you were a mod you could [abuse the hell out of it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134200/148672)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter I don't see myself having any need for that I just thought it might have been a reporting bug to need to be looked into..