# Is using this downvote/delete loophole exploitative?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, trusted-user

As a [trusted user on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user), one of my privileges is

> Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower

Add to this the fact that votes can be withdrawn within a grace period, and it's possible for me to do this:

1. See a 'bad' answer with a score of zero
2. Downvote it
3. Refresh the page
4. Vote to delete it
5. Withdraw my downvote

Thus achieving what it would seem the privilege is specifically *not* granting me, namely the ability to cast delete votes on *zero*-scoring answers. After the above actions, the answer has a score of zero, but *does* still have my vote-to-delete on it (downvoting again and refreshing shows `delete(1)`).

How OK / not-OK is it for me to do this?

Comment: [Moderators can vote as much as they want](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134200/moderators-can-vote-as-much-as-they-want).

Comment: @thirtydot: I think he meant more the "I have the privilege to delete-vote -1 scored questions, but see, I can do it with 0 scored questions, too!" thingy...

Comment: @GardenGnobobby: I agree. I linked to it mainly as an example of another "downvote exploit".

Comment: No exploit; it's no different than editing a post for the mere reason of undoing a vote. You should not do it, but it's neither a loophole nor exploit of the system.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's no point to that. Once the deletion goes through, all the rep lost from downvoting the question will be restored.

Even worse, by un-downvoting the question, you're making it hard for *others* to vote to delete as well. Since you obviously want the question gone, this is rather counterproductive, yes?

Yeah, you can "exploit" this. But not to any worthwhile end.

Oh, and let's not forget: you have to have **20K rep** to vote to delete. If you honestly still care about that -1 (especially since it's temporary), well that's a deep, personal issue about which there's nothing we can (or should) do.