# Why does the new review page sometimes show "Recommend Deletion," instead of "Delete"?

Tags: support, review

I notice that when I review low quality posts, I sometimes have a "Recommend Deletion" button, instead of the usual "Delete" one. For example, it happens in the following cases:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/257
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/218
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/126
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/78
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/236
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/11
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/232
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/152
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/212
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/185

Those are consecutive posts I reviewed, and for which I didn't see the "Delete" button as I was expecting.

What is the difference?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have an example post for which this occurs? I'd assume it would tell you to Recommend when the post isn't eligible for deletion by you.

Comment: I am a 20k user, and none of the posts were mine. Are there cases where a 20k user cannot vote to delete?

Comment: Can't you only vote to delete answers that have a score of -1 or lower?

Comment: Guess: You only see the `Delete` button for negative score posts.

Comment: you can only vote to delete closed questions and answers with a score of -1 or less

Comment: Whoops… That's true. The page is for reviewing low quality posts, not posts voted to be deleted. Now, an answer would say what happens when the score is not negative, and I click on "Recommend Deletion."

Comment: `1 If you don't have enough rep to delete, you can "Recommend Deletion". This doesn't do anything right now except move it to the front of the queue for people who can delete it.` I guess the same applies, it does nothing yet.

Comment: @DanielFischer The difference is that nobody can actually vote to delete an answer with a positive score. `:)`

Comment: (Except the owner ;) or moderators, if you call that a vote). Yes. That's also a point for "nothing happens". I think some functionality is planned, like if enough high-rep users recommend deletion it gets deleted nevertheless, or downvoted, whatever. Wait for the team to clarify, they should know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deletion of answers by 20k+ users [requires the post be negatively scored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user). As of right now, the posts you listed are all 0 scored<sup>1</sup>, thus are not eligible to be voted on for deletion.

Aside: I've proposed [that this be slightly modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137200/delete-votes-on-0-scored-answers-should-count-as-a-down-vote) as it's just a nuisance.

<sup>Note 1: save [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/257) which I assume happened after you linked to it, as it isn't eligible to be reviewed anymore.</sup>

Comment: And Geoff wrote in [New Feature: Community Review Tasks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137174/new-feature-community-review-tasks): *If you don't have enough rep to delete, you can "Recommend Deletion". This doesn't do anything right now except move it to the front of the queue for people who can delete it.* So, I guess for non-negative voted answers, such answers would move up in the queue for moderators?