# Recommend deletion is treated as a delete vote for 20k users

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-delete

In the low quality posts queue, the "Delete" button changes to "Recommend deletion" when a 20k user runs out of delete votes.

However, it's still treated as a vote to delete, causing the "You have reached the maximum of *n* Deletion votes per day" error:

[image: Recommend deletion causing a vote to delete error]

It should work like it does for sub-20kers: move the post to the top of the queue for people who still have delete votes.

Comment: It is also slightly questionable if 20k users should be able to delete zero score answers here, which is not allowed in other places.

Comment: I thought it didn't actually delete 0 scored posts. (at least last time I looked there were not delete votes getting attached and I still had some left)

Comment: @BoPersson I agree: I feature requested something similar, but [I don't think it's working as intended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143569/149432). In this case, the post was at -1: I just ran out of delete votes for the day.

Comment: @Flexo It does register as a delete vote: if you go back and downvote the post, the delete vote shows up and you get the "you have already voted to delete this post" error if you try to vote to delete again.

Comment: I think I'd rather have more delete votes. This new review system is so efficient that I can easily burn through all 30 of mine in under an hour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recommend delete will work correctly after running out of delete votes for the day.  This will be fixed in the next build.