# Recommend deletion by trusted user

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete, moderator-abilities

According to [Recommend deletion is treated as a delete vote for 20k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144310/168244), a trusted user's (20K+ reputation) delete votes could turn into recommendations (Recommend Deletion) after running out of them on a per-day basis. However, on the fairly small [Low Quality Review Queue on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/50687) it seemed to happen without being out of delete votes.

[image]

Why is this? Perhaps a bug?

Comment: did the answer have positive score or was it accepted? my recollection is, in cases like that 20Kers votes degrade into toothless "recommendations"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), not a bug. Only posts with *negative score* can be deleted outright by trusted users; see the [trusted user privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including:
>
> - Voting to delete answers **with score of -1 or lower**

Emphasis mine. In the Low Quality Review queue that limit is [raised to 0 or lower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230872/why-im-casting-delete-votes-in-the-low-quality-review-queue/230873#230873) to save you having to downvote first. But this still means that if the score of the post is 1 or higher, even trusted users only get to *recommend* deletion.

For example, I have 20k+ here on Meta, but for [this review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/30605) (post visible to 10k+ only) the post in question had a score of +2 when I voted to delete, so my vote was recorded as a recommendation rather than an outright deletion vote.

Comment: Isn't that threshold increased to 0 when in the LQP queue? I thought I had read that somewhere. Maybe I'm imagining things again.

Comment: @animuson: I don't think so, but I am not 100% sure about that either.

Comment: Found it: *"Review gives you a bit of a boost by allowing you to vote to delete 0-scored answers. This is done just to save you the step of having to down-vote them first and then vote to delete."* - [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230873)

Comment: @animuson: Ah! Yes, I recall having seen that exact post too! Updated my answer to reflect this.