# Why I'm casting delete votes in the Low Quality review queue?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

Well, all NAA's and LQ's flags are being pushed to the LQ review queue. I'm a 20k user but that doesn't mean I want to use my delete votes on 0 scored answers, in fact I cannot vote on them outside the queue. Then why are my votes used?

Comment: "in fact I cannot vote on them outside the queue" - [you *sort of* can](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135073/)

Comment: @AakashM not if they are 0 scored or positive scored.

Comment: If they are zero scored you can downvote them, refresh, delete-vote.

Answer (score 15):

Don't really see the problem here. You get X number of delete votes per day (between 5 and 30, [depending on reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) - so by the time you can vote to delete answers, you'll have at least 15). You can use them on whatever you want: questions or answers.

Review gives you a bit of a boost by allowing you to vote to delete 0-scored answers. This is done just to save you the step of having to down-vote them first and *then* vote to delete.

20K+ users can clear out low-quality reviews faster than normal users, as it takes only 3 votes (vs 6 recommendations) to delete posts. However, if you use up all of your votes for the day you'll only be able to *recommend* deletion, and your recommendation carries no more weight than anyone else's.

If you're regularly running out of delete votes and notice a backlog of either questions or low-quality posts developing (either inside or outside of /review) then *that* could be a problem.

Comment: It seems to me that many questions still need 6 votes to get deleted as there are not that many 20k+ users.  Would you be able to get some stats for Stack Overflow on how many answers get deleted with 1 or 2 20K delete's on them vs 3 votes?  to me any answer that gets deleted with 6 votes even though a 20K user voted seems like a waste of the delete vote.